# Javascript replace all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I am working on a loop to replace language tags `{lang_vname}` with the actual term (name)

language.js:

```
var lang = {
//common
   vname                   : "name",
   name                    : "lastname",
   adress                  : "adress",
   language                : "language",
```

replace script

```
function translate(output)  {
var term = output;
$.each(lang,function(i,l){
    var find = "{lang_"+i+"}";
    term = term.replace(find,l);
});
return term;}
```

I can't figure out how to replace the output if there is more than one expression of one kind. It's only replacing the first one and if there is a second tag of it it displays the tag.
I found a solution like `replace(/find/g,l);` but it is not working here and stops my whole script.
Is there a way to solve that easily ?

EDIT

thanks to Felix Kling! the link he provided made it work :D my final result is

```
function translate(output)  {
    var term = output;
    $.each(lang,function(i,l){
        var find = "{lang_"+i+"}";
        var regex = new RegExp(find, "g");
        term = term.replace(regex, l);  
    });
    return term;
}
```

thanks for your fast help!

Comment: what is the format and type of the output variable ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Javascript, how can i perform a global replace on string with a variable inside '/' and '/g'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542232/in-javascript-how-can-i-perform-a-global-replace-on-string-with-a-variable-insi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this won't work for you please provide an example for the variable output

```
function translate(output)  {
    var term = output;
    $.each(lang, function(i, l){
        var find = new RegExp("{lang_"+i+"}", "g");
        term = term.replace(find, l);
    });
    return term;

}
```

Comment: something like this for example :

var output = "<div class="link" id="1" url="/include/php/startseite.php">{lang_link_start}</div><div class="link subnavi" id="2">{lang_link_jobs}</div>";

its working for single expressions but as soon as there is sth twice its not replacing both

Comment: yes i combined both but the link by Felix Kling helped me to understand the issue :)
thanks for your help