# str.replace only for selected radio button text

Tags: javascript, html

Right now str.replace is only working for 1st row , i want str.replace to work on selected radio button row.

```
<tr>
    <td><input onclick="myFunction()" type="radio" name="test" value="1"></td>
    <td id = "demo">System Architect1 #BLANK1# test #BLANK2#</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input onclick="myFunction()" type="radio" name="test" value="2"></td>
    <td id = "demo">System Architect2 #BLANK1# test #BLANK2#</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input onclick="myFunction()" type="radio" name="test" value="3"></td>
    <td id = "demo">System Architect3 #BLANK1# test #BLANK2#</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
</tr>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("#BLANK1#", "<input type='text' name='BLANK1' maxlength='50' />")
.replace("#BLANK2#", "<input type='text' name='BLANK2' maxlength='50' />")
.replace("#BLANK3#", "<input type='text' name='BLANK3' maxlength='50' />")
.replace("#BLANK4#", "<input type='text' name='BLANK4' maxlength='50' />");
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Javascript, how can i perform a global replace on string with a variable inside '/' and '/g'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542232/in-javascript-how-can-i-perform-a-global-replace-on-string-with-a-variable-insi) - Check the most upvoted answer, not the accepted one.

Comment: You can NOT have the same id multiple times in html. The `$('#demo')` will always return the first one.
Try demo1, demo2, demo3, and `myFunction('demo1'), myFunction('demo2')` ... and `function myFunction(id)` and `getElementById(id)`

Comment: @SélimAchour , Yes its working now, but only 1 issue - its keep on str replace for previously selected radio button.

Comment: then `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = res;`

Comment: @SélimAchour , yes i had already done that ,but no success, It keeps input box for previously selected radio buttons, I only want input box for currently selected radio button only.

Comment: @SélimAchour but my 90% work is done by your suggestion, Thank you for that

Comment: @Metu007 sorry I could not understand the last problem. You should create a codepen if possible

Comment: @SélimAchour here is the link - https://jsfiddle.net/1u2kcgje/  when i change radio button  its keep input box for previously selected radio button.

Comment: @SélimAchour I only want Input box for currently selected radio button , not for previously selected radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually use the same id for every similar element. This is the reason why it is always replacing the first row.

Further, to actually do this, you have to change the id's first and then do some like this :

```
<tr>
    <td><input onclick="myFunction(this)" type="radio" name="test" value="1"></td>
    <td id = "demo1">System Architect1 #BLANK1# test #BLANK2#</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input onclick="myFunction(this)" type="radio" name="test" value="1"></td>
    <td id = "demo2">System Architect2 #BLANK1# test #BLANK2#</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
</tr>
```

Following is by using Jquery but you can do it by javascript also if you are not using any jquery

```
<script>
    function myFunction(element) {
  
  var str = $(element).parent().next().html();
    var res = str.replace("#BLANK1#", "<input type='text' name='BLANK1' maxlength='50' />")
    .replace("#BLANK2#", "<input type='text' name='BLANK2' maxlength='50' />")
    .replace("#BLANK3#", "<input type='text' name='BLANK3' maxlength='50' />")
    .replace("#BLANK4#", "<input type='text' name='BLANK4' maxlength='50' />");
   $(element).parent().next().html(res);  
   
}
    </script>
```